# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo, Runtime and NullPointer exceptions

Tags: java, android-studio

I get that error whenever I attempt to run this app. It's simple right now, I'm just trying to make sure the first button does what I want it to. It also mentions NullPointerException.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        calendarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setComponent(cn);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
}
```

This (and declaring the buttons) are all I have done in the activity's Java file. I have set placeholders for listeners on other buttons but commented them out until I figure this one.

I have tried starting a new project running the same code (even pieced the layout back together) to make sure the Manifest wasn't accidentally messed with. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I derped. Hard. I assigned the button variables a value during instantiation (which I have above onCreate) rather than INSIDE onCreate. I fixed it myself. Sorry about that.